# Empty recycle bin with Powershell V2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, recycle-bin

Is there a way to empty the recycle bin using Powershell 2.0.

I do not want to update Powershell.

Comment: is there a requirement not to update PowerShell ? Any specific reason ?

Comment: The Recycle Bin is just a folder on the file system. The answer is YES.

Comment: @jww reason ? There's a cmdlet called `Clear-RecycleBin` why don't you update and make use of it

Comment: @jww: Actually it's a folder per volume and the Shell folder is an aggregate of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could clear recycle bin via com object. Like so:

```
$Shell= New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$Bin = $Shell.NameSpace(10)
foreach ($Item in @($Bin.Items())){Remove-item $Item.Path -Force}
```

Comment: `$bin.Items() | % Path | Remove-Item -Force` would be a pipeline option.

Answer (score 1):

You could also directly call [SHEmptyRecycleBin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shemptyrecyclebinw) Win32 function:

```
$definition = @'
[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, string pszRootPath, uint dwFlags);
'@
$winApi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $definition -Name WinAPI -Namespace Extern -PassThru
$winApi::SHEmptyRecycleBin(0, $null, 7)
```

All recycle bins are deleted, no confirmation message is shown, no progress bar, no sound.